# Selecting a corresponding strategy based on the subtype of the instance

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have an interface `IResponse` that represents a response to a `Question` and a few concrete response types that implement `IResponse`:

```
interface IResponse<out TQuestion> where TQuestion: Question
{
     TQuestion Question { get; }
     Candidate Candidate { get; }
     string Answer { get; }
}

class MultipleChoiceResponse : IResponse<MultipleChoiceQuestion>
{
    public MultipleChoiceQuestion Question { get; }
    public Candidate Candidate { get; }
    public string Answer { get; }
}

class TextResponse : IResponse<TextQuestion>
{
    public TextQuestion Question { get; }
    public Candidate Candidate { get; }
    public string Answer { get; }
}
...

abstract class Question {..}
class MultipleChoiceQuestion : Question {..}
class TextQuestion : Question {..}
...
```

For each response type, I have a corresponding response evaluator that implements `IResponseEvaluator`:

```
interface IResponseEvaluator<TQuestion, TResponse> 
    where TQuestion : Question
    where TResponse : IResponse<TQuestion>
{
    decimal Evaluate(TResponse response);
}

class DefaultMultipleChoiceResponseEvaluator : IResponseEvaluator<MultipleChoiceQuestion, MultipleChoiceResponse>
{
    public decimal Evaluate(MultipleChoiceResponse response)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class DefaultTextResponseEvaluator : IResponseEvaluator<TextQuestion, TextResponse>
{
    public decimal Evaluate(TextResponse response)
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Finally, I have an `EvaluationAggregator` with a method `EvaluateAll` that provides a common interface to accept a collection of all subtypes of `IResponse` using `IEnumerable<IResponse<Question>>`:

```
class EvaluationAggregator
{
    public IResponseEvaluator<MultipleChoiceQuestion, MultipleChoiceResponse> ChoiceEvaluator { get; set; }   

    public IResponseEvaluator<TextQuestion, TextResponse> TextEvaluator { get; set; }

    ...
    
    public decimal EvaluateAll(IEnumerable<IResponse<Question>> responses)
    {
         decimal totalScore = 0;
         foreach (var response in responses)
         {
              decimal score = response switch
              {
                  MultipleChoiceResponse mcr => ChoiceEvaluator.Evaluate(mcr),
                  TextResponse tr => TextEvaluator.Evaluate(tr),
                  ...
              };
              totalScore += score;
         }    
         return totalScore;
    }
}
```

Since, `TQuestion` in `IResponse<TQuestion>` is covariant(marked with `out`), I can pass responses to all question subtypes as a single `IEnumerable` to `EvaluateAll`. However, to select the right evaluator for the type, I'm still having to switch on the type of the response. If I add more response types in the future, the code will have to be modified to add a case for each new type. Is there a design pattern or a cleaner way to do this?

This is how I would initialize `EvaluationAggregator` using a builder and then call it:

```
IEnumerable<IResponse<Question>> responses = FetchAllTypesOfResponses();

var aggregator = new EvaluationAggregatorBuilder() 
    .UseChoiceEvaluator(new DefaultMultipleChoiceResponseEvaluator())
    .UseTextEvaluator(new DefaultMultipleChoiceResponseEvaluator())
    ..OtherEvaluators()
    .Build();
};

decimal totalScore = aggregator.EvaluateAll(responses);
```

I'm using C# 10.